# Declaring an heterogeneous Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, program-entry-point, heterogeneous

It doesn't recognize `item[1]` I guess it's because the method is declared as a string in `public static void main(STRING[] args)`. But how else should I declare the main method in oder to have the Integers accepted?

This is the message Eclips comes up with: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    at Package1.test7.main(test7.java:18)`

```java
// import java.util.arrays;

public class test7

{    



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    Object[][] items = new String[2][]; 
    items[0] = new String[]{"a", "b"}; 
(18)items[1] = new Integer[]{1, 2, 4}; 


    System.out.println (items[0]);

    }   

}
```

Comment: `Object[][] items = new Object[2][];`

Comment: Initialize the array like so `Object[][] items = new Object[2][];` and remove that `(18)`.

Comment: @Alex R. Thanks. Pretty weid, I copied it from https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/02/6-example-to-declare-two-dimensional-array-in-java.html.
I know about that 18, that was only to show that that was line #18.

Comment: Hard to believe that something you read on the internet wasn't true (;->).  What's the world coming to?

Comment: This guy probably just made a mistake. Take a look in the comment section of the article, there are people pointing that out.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson, thanks you too, Not bad for a Tennis player!! ;-)